# Can not boot Pi 4 B, Keeps looping Emergency mode: Help

Tags: boot-issues

I'm not able to boot my Pi 4B or access the console. I can not enter after Emergency mode. It keeps looping back to this after hitting enter. I have the SD card inserted. Is this SD card related or the Pi hardware? What are my next steps?  Thanks

[image]

After I hit enter it loops back:

[image]

Comment: Certainly looks like it might be SD related. Since its timing out trying to access the filesystem. If you have another card around I would try imaging it and see what that does.   It could also be related to somehow having the wrong UUID in place for the SD card, but that seems less likely unless you have been messing with boot related settings/files.

Comment: based on your previous question, the drive that you mount on /home/pi/backup has either failed, is not connected, or you've changed the partitions uuid, or messed with /etc/fstab

Comment: If you want to save whats on the sd card (i.e. not re image it from scratch), you'll need a way to boot the pi from a clean image - e.g. USB thumb drive - I'm assuming that your pi4 is able to boot from USB of course - or you can boot a clean install from another SD card as long as you have a USB sd card adapter to read your current sd card

Comment: So I ended up flashing a backup image of my project to another SD card and it still wouldn't boot. It wasn't until I plugged in the external USB HDD that it would boot successfully. I didn't realize that you can't boot without the USB storage drive connected. Is that normal behavior?